# Spring boot execute 2 methods simultaneously

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I'm having a spring boot controller witch at post request executes 2 methods that return 2 lists, and those 2 lists are sent to the view page.
Those 2 methods need like 15 seconds to run each so it would take 30-40 second for the controller to send those list into the page.How would I be able to execute those methods simultaneously and reduce time?I've tried something using threads but it didn't do anything:(

```
@RequestMapping(path = "search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String searchPage(@ModelAttribute("specification") Specification specification, Model model) throws InterruptedException {

        List<SearchResult1> list1;
        List<SearchResult2> lista2;

        list1 = service1.search(params);

        list2 = service2.search(params);

        model.addAttribute("list1", list1);

        model.addAttribute("list2", list2);


        return "home";
    }
```

Comment: *I've tried something using threads but it didn't do anything:(* so you did it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your `search` methods async, either using thread executors pool, or `@Async`, you will be able to invoke them at once, and gather results after finish.

Just remember, that you will have to use `Future` for this.

So something like this will be

```
@Async
public Future<List<Whatever>> search(whatever here){
      resultList=whateverYouDoThere();
      return new AsyncResult<Whatever>(resultList);   
}
```

in both services ofc, and invocations:

```
   List<Whatever> completeList=new ArrayList():
   Future<Whatever> fut1=service1.search(...);
   Future<Whateva> fut2=service2.search(...);
   completeList.addAll(fut1.get());
   completeList.addAll(fut2.get();
    //here you got all the stuff in completeList
```

I skipped your case here as I was too lazy to read it carefuly, so in your case it would be

```
Future<SearchResult1> fut1=service1.search(params);

Future<SerchResult2> fut2 = service2.search(params);

model.addAttribute("list1", fut1.get());

model.addAttribute("list2", fut2.get());
```

or something very similar

Comment: So i just need to add Future to both the methods and that's it?or do i have to still add async annotation for each method inside the implementation?

Comment: Depends on implementation. If you don't use @Async, you will have to submit your invoacation to thread pool. But since you can do that with annotation..... And remember that you have to return `AsycnResult` as `Future`

Answer (score 0):

You can use executor service to submit threads then wait for their return before continuing:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchPage(@ModelAttribute("specification") Specification specification, Model model) throws InterruptedException {

  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

  List<Callable<Map<String, List<?>>>> callables = new ArrayList<>();

  Callable<Map<String, List<?>>> callable1 = new Callable<Map<String,List<?>>>() {

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<?>> call() throws Exception {
      Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
      map.put("list1", service1.search(params));
      return map;
    }
  };
  callables.add(callable1);

  Callable<Map<String, List<?>>> callable2 = new Callable<Map<String,List<?>>>() {

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<?>> call() throws Exception {
      Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
      map.put("list2", service2.search(params));
      return map;
    }
  };
  callables.add(callable2);

  List<Future<Map<String, List<?>>>> futures = executor.invokeAll(callables);

  for (Future<Map<String, List<?>>> f : futures) {
    Map<String, List<?>> results = f.get();
    Entry<String, List<?>> res = results.entrySet().iterator().next();
    model.addAttribute(res.getKey(), res.getValue());
  }

  return "home";
}
```

Essentially you'll be submitting these tasks and the call to `future.get()` will wait for the return. I changed it up slightly so the results are in a map where the key is the list name and the value is the search results.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! I'll see what i can do with both answers :D